# Recovering unsaved jupyter notebook

Tags: python, google-chrome, jupyter-notebook, recovery

I just got two days worth of work vanished because jupyter notebook was not able to save (_xsrf argument missing).
I browse the internet for solutions:

- looking at the running directory in jupyter
- looking at the saved version in jupyter (there are none in my case)

I am starting to look at the chrome logs to at least see everything I typed but they are binary. Would you know where I could find logs of everything that was typed on chrome ? Or any other solution to retrieve that code ? You would be my savior !

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and was able to recover all of my code from the 'history.sqlite' file in the following directory: ~/.ipython/profile_default/
(on Windows it's C:/Users/USERNAME/.ipython/profile_default/history.sqlite).

This is a file that saves all commands that were issued to the IPython kernel. At the end of the file (opened in a text editor) I found my most recent commands from the Jupyter notebook. This will only work if you did actually run your code though, not if it was just written.
Some more information is on the website where I found this solution: https://medium.com/flatiron-engineering/recovering-from-a-jupyter-disaster-27401677aeeb

Comment: Thanks a lot. it works! Although it is still difficult to get the correct lines from the history. I was panicking.

Comment: I came across this answer and tried using it for a while. However, sorting out the resulting `history.sqlite`was not easy. Instead, you should use the answer here, which is much easier: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60047280/1379826